# How to use Tesseract OCR and PassportEye in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I have installed locally **Tesseract OCR** and **PassportEye** to retreive the **MRZ **found in a given **ID Dounment** (ID Card and Passport). And It works normally.
But My question is how can I use these two tools in **AWS lambda** to get the MRZ informations ?

All I want is get MRZ data using tesseract and passportEye in aws lambda